# Android Drawable under a word in a TextView

Tags: android

I have a requirement to place a drawable under a certain word of a multi line TextView. How can do this ? One way might to use use multiple TextView and place a drawable bottom below the EditText that needs the drawable .Is their a easier way to do this ?

Kind Regards

Answer (score 1):

Probably, http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/BackgroundColorSpan.html
is something you need? Or any combination of spannables.

Comment: My requirement is to underline a word with a drawable ? Will a image span do ?

Comment: Read http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/CharacterStyle.html subclasses and choose what you like.

Answer (score 1):

This may meet your need.

`android:drawableBottom="@drawable/{yourdrawable}`

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:drawableBottom

Answer (score 1):

Its possible to placed drawable between text , You have to use spannable.See example of emoti icon in between text.

```
Textview textview = (Textview)findViewById(R.id.textview);
textview.setText(getSmiledText(text.toString()));

public Spannable getSmiledText(String text) {
        SpannableStringBuilder builder = new SpannableStringBuilder(text);
        if (emoticons.size() > 0) {
            int index;
            for (index = 0; index < builder.length(); index++) {
                if (Character.toString(builder.charAt(index)).equals(":")) {
                    for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : emoticons.entrySet()) {
                        int length = entry.getKey().length();
                        if (index + length > builder.length())
                            continue;
                        if (builder.subSequence(index, index + length).toString().equals(entry.getKey())) {
                            builder.setSpan(new ImageSpan(getContext(), entry.getValue()), index, index + length, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                            index += length - 1;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return builder;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would simply suggest you to set `html formatted text` inside `TextView` in such a way that you can apply inline style to apply `background image for desired text` content.